# Date/Time exactly 6 hours behind Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, calendar

I have a TimePickerDialog called from the onDateSetListener of a DatePickerDialog in order to allow the user to pick both the date and time one after the other. I store the information in a Calendar object `calendar`. When the user is finished, they click to save this and other information in the database. The relevant piece that saves the time is here

`call.setContactTimestamp(new DateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));`

Where `setContactTimestamp()` saves an org.joda.time.DateTime object to the table. This all seems to be fine. I then display this (and other) data back to the user later using this relevant code
`TextView dateTime = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.date_time);
dateTime.setText(sdf.format(calls.get(i).getContactTimestamp().getMillis()));`

Where sdf is a SimpleDateFormat that looks like this `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);`

**Issue:** The time displayed is always exactly 6 hours behind local time and the time that is being displayed on the device. I have followed breakpoints through and what really has me confused is right before the data gets saved, I evaluate `sdf.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis())` and it shows the accurate time. When I pull the information back, the milliseconds are off.

**Example:** I opened my Date/TimePickerDialogs and it had the current Date and Time selected, January 5th 2017 at 8:47:36 AM. I clicked to save this, and evaluated on the save statement shown above. 
`new DateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis())` evaluated to `2017-01-05T08:47:36.322-06:00`, which was `1483627656322` millis. 
I then pulled the information for display, and the returning joda.time.DateTime evaluated to `2017-01-05T08:47:36.000Z` which was `1483606056000` millis, exactly 6 hours behind what I saved at 2:47:36AM.

Here is my DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog in case it is relevant. If I have left anything out you think is important please let me know, I will add it.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog();
dpd.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog();
        tpd.setOnTimeSetListener(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                callDateTime.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        });
        tpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "tdp");
    }
});
dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dpd");
```

Comment: Can you replace SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US) with  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.getDefault()); and try once?

Comment: No luck but I was mistaken. The discrepancy must be in this line `call.setContactTimestamp(new DateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));`. For example I save 1483639217000 millis but then I retrieve 1483617617000 millis. I still don't see why it is saving then pulling different millis? Would creating the DateTime object from the millis be causing this?

Comment: So, You are converting java time to jodatime and while getting you have jodatime try converting that to java time as: new DateTime(calls.get(i).getContactTimestamp()).toCalendar(Locale.getDefault()) and try?

Comment: It still displayed the same time, 6 hours behind. I removed the vague example and gave an exact example, showing exactly what things evaluated to. I think it has to be a discrepancy in the save. I am not sure if I am doing something incorrectly or if this is something occuring on my database I am unaware of.

Comment: Always as soon as I ask on stackoverflow I seem to arrive at the conclusion.. It was an error in how I was saving. I needed to replace `call.setContactTimestamp(new DateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));` to save in UTC using `call.setContactTimestamp(dateUtil.convertToUtc(new DateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis())));`.  Dates and Times are really my weakest point. Thanks for all your help. You can post this as answer if you like or I will later

Comment: Post it as answer @wizloc. It might help somebody:)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
```

May helps you!

Comment: It can be because of TimeZone issue!

Comment: Sorry this didnt work, but I was also mistaken. Please read my edit.

Comment: What is **dpd** and **tdp**?

Comment: DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog